# How to handle tags in xml content in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, stax

I have to insert a sub-xml into another xml in java.
The sub-xml contains tags in content:

```
<paragraph>
 One paragraph <bold>The title <link> a link </link> morewords</bold>
</paragraph>
```

How can I handle this? The tags should be on the same place after insertion.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

As an example, your XML will look like this-

```
<example>
<![CDATA[<paragraph>
 One paragraph <bold>The title <link> a link </link> morewords</bold>
</paragraph>]]></example>
```

There is another alternative as well, but above one is better.

```
&lt;paragraph&gt;
 One paragraph &lt;bold&gt;The title &lt;link&gt; a link &lt;/link&gt; morewords&lt;/bold&gt;
&lt;/paragraph&gt;
```

Most of XML parser and XML libraries support special character `escaping` and `remove escaping`.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I use CDATA, the tags will not be recognized as tags when I insert the subdocument in the main document with DOM?